# Run PHP scripts inside Rails app

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I have a Rails application that needs to integrate [Arrowchat](http://www.arrowchat.com/), a chat plugin. Because it heavily relies on PHP -- even the client JS/CSS is generated from PHP scripts, I've reached the conclusion that I have to run PHP (and ruby) scripts within html.erb pages. Is that even possible ?

If it's any use, I have Phusion Passenger along with Apache, that obviously can serve php in standalone fashion.

Comment: just add a handler in apache to take care of the chat like `/chat/` and add all the php files...that is it.

Comment: @GabrielSosa Could you be more specific ? I don't have much trouble running the php app by itself. The main problem is that the client part of the chat solution has to be displayed in an *.erb page, where only ruby injections are interpreted on the server-side.

Comment: Have you considered an iframe?  Cheap, easy, convenient, and the simplest thing that could possibly work.

Comment: @Charles: I sure did, problem is it can't exactly fit the chat UI (think Facebook), unless I allow it to take much whitespace - which is out of question.